# How to get images from get request inside gallery on angular 10 using ng-gallery for angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, get, image-gallery

I am stuck at some hard code method to bring images from an api directly into the gallery or lightbox...
I coudn't find any tutorials , so i found this example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-gallery-imageviewer

And i tried to change it for my code and I managed to get images in arrays , but I don't know how to pass them into property like this dude does or something similar..

I'm stuck at this point where I must pass my images to that variable with some properties:

[image]

My code:

```
 allImages: PostG[] = [];

fetch(this.apiKey)
  .then(response => {
    if (response.ok) {
      return response.json();
    };
  })
  .then((j: any) => {
   
    const image = [...j.data.post.map(item => item.images)];
    
    image.forEach((image: PostG[]) => {
      var obj = {
        image:image,
      }
      this.allImages = [...image];
  return{
        type: "imageViewer",
        imagesGallery: {
        srcUrl: console.log(this.allImages),
        previewUrl: console.log(this.allImages)
      }
    }
  });
});
```

This code gives me this result below.

[image]

If you can check the stackblitz you can see in that example he use local images , in my case how i should manage to get my photos ?
I want to *ngFor every gallery for each post I get with the post images..

Here is my HTML as i tried to do:

```
<ion-col class="ion-no-padding" size-md="12" size-lg="12" size-sm="12" size-xs="12" *ngFor="let post of allPosts | sortPipe"> 

//then the gallery inside:

<div class="basic-container">
    <h2>Basic Example</h2>
    <gallery id="basic-test" fluid [items]="items" [itemTemplate]="itemTemplate" [gestures]="false"></gallery>
  </div>

  <!-- create a template to use the imageviewer -->
  <ng-template #itemTemplate let-index="index" let-type="type" let-data="{{this.allImages}}" let-currIndex="currIndex">
    <ng-container *ngIf="type === 'imageViewer' && index === currIndex" >
      <ngx-imageviewer [src]="this.allImages"></ngx-imageviewer>
    </ng-container>
  </ng-template>
```

Sorry if my question is too long , i just want to give you all the info for helping me. I need this for a big project. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create JSON from your response according to `ngx-gallery`.

for more explanation check this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-gallery-imageviewer-ycxijv?file=src/app/home/home.component.html).

i tried to create the same scenario as currently you are facing right now

try something like this.

```
this.response.data.post.forEach(post => {
  post.galleryImages = post.images.map(image => {
    return new ImageItem({ src: image, thumb: image });
  });
});
```

and after JSON creation in your HTML file

```
<div class="basic-container" *ngFor="let post of response.data.post; let i=index">
    <h2>{{post.title}}</h2>
    <p>{{post.description}}</p>
    <gallery id="basic-test_{{i}}" fluid [items]="post.galleryImages" [gestures]="false">
    </gallery>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello man! Thank you so much for helping. Your code is good, but it seems I get all the photos in the gallery and a lot of errors of type: ``` ERROR TypeError: name.toLowerCase is not a function ```. I guess I should somehow use *ngFor so that typescript will know how to set the exact photos to specific post and gallery..

Comment: It looks like this.. however its still a progress. : LInk: [link](https://i.ibb.co/c102356/gallery.jpg)

Comment: oh i got it. so you want to show the photos according to post. will update my answer according to this.

Comment: can you share your api response in your question as well.

Comment: sure my friend , this is the api : [link](https://carsworld.herokuapp.com/api/v1/post/get-all-posts-unprotected)

Comment: I have to go now man , if you find anything pls post i will check later. ty

Comment: i have updated the code. please check the latest [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-gallery-imageviewer-rzmlwa?file=src/app/home/home.component.ts).

Comment: yes it is good , but what if someone update something on the api.. the photos will not update as well :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224149/discussion-between-farhat-zaman-and-aquaforce).